# ASP.NET GridView with DataBinding: toggle column visibility

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, code-behind, markup

I've got an ASP.NET GridView bound to an ObjectDataSource where columns are not automatically generated. Now I want to display one row (containing the link to the edit-page) based on the permission of the user. I've got an method which does all the permission checks and returns a simple boolean value describing the visibility of the row. Now my markup looks somewhat like this:

```
<Columns>
    <%-- Some important information rows --%>

    <asp:TemplateField Visible='<%= CanEditRows() %>'>
        <%-- Column content --%>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

However this somehow allways results in an error:

> Object of type System.Boolean cannot be created from String '<%=
>   CanEditRows() %>' and assigned to the Visible-property.

(or something in this way...)

I've also tried to toggle the column visibility from code-behind inside the DataBound or DataBinding-Events of the GridView, but everything I tried was unsuccessfull...

Can anybody help me out? :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the return type of "CanEditRows()"?Is it string or bool?

Comment: "I've got an method which does all the permission checks and returns a simple boolean value describing the visibility of the row" - It's boolean, sorry for the missunderstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this code

```
 <asp:TemplateField Visible=<%# CanEditRows() %> >
```

Comment: I've already did, but it tells me that this syntax is only valid for bound fields... I forgot to mention that I am forced to apply data binding from code-behind... so of course the parser cannot find any databind for first! 
And that's the solution! :D I am only able to toggle columns visibility if there are columns at all... thank you all! ;)

Comment: I'am happy to help you Aschratt